# How to find all active network interfaces for given IP in RHEL using ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, rhel

For e.g. IP=192.168.0.110, assign this IP to network interfaces eth0 ,eth1 etc, and ping the gateway. If given interface able to ping the gateway then we can identify as active network interface. How can we do that in ruby?

Comment: You're looking for a chef recipe? This seems more like a question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the data collected by Ohai under `node['network']['interfaces']`. The exact code I'll leave to you since it depends on your needs but run `ohai network | less` to see what the data looks like. Also we already figure out the IP of the default interface and put it in `node['ipaddress']` if that's useful.